# Probability Axiom Related Question

Tags: probability, statistics

If $P$ is a probability measure on a sample space $\Omega$, show that the function $P/2$ satisfies [Kolmogorov's Axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Axioms) (I) and (III) but not (II). The function $P^2$ satisfies (I) and (II) but not necessarily (III); give a counterexample to (III).

I was trying to solve it for the last few hours but was unable to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Ummm... what are Axions I, II, and III???

Comment: My bad, edited it

Comment: $P/2$ obviously does *not* satisfy II. If $P(\Omega)=1$ clearly $P(\Omega)/2\neq1$. On the other hand, $P^2$ does satisfy II, but not III. Because square of a sum is not the sum of squares.

Comment: How should I prove it? I'm just super lost.

Comment: @Hello:  for a counterexample you just need one.  Find a distribution that satisfies all three axioms where the square does not satisfy III.  You should be able to do that with a small discrete distribution.

Comment: @RossMillikan - or indeed find any distribution where the probability is not concentrated at a single point

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $P(A) >0, P(B) >0$ and $A\cap B$ is empty. Then $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$. If $P^{2}$ is also additive you get $(P(A\cup B))^{2}=P^{2}(A)+P^{2}(B)$ so $(P(A)+P(B))^{2}=P^{2}(A)+P^{2}(B)$. These two equations give $P(A)P(B)=0$ which is false. So $P^{2}$ cannot satisfy the three axioms as long as there is a least one pair of sets $A$ and $B$ which are disjoint  and $P(A)>0,P(B) >0$.